Conditions for a first order recursion relation to have a limit
Given a recursion relation
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+s(x_{n-1})$$
for real valued $x_m$ and some function $s(x)$ which satisfies $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}s(x)=0$. Are there any necessary conditions for $s(x)$'s asymptotic behavior as $|x|\to\infty$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n<\infty$ for any initial condition $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$?
I am looking for some condition on $s(x)$ like $s(x) = O(f(x))$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

If $|s(x_{n - 1})|$ is small and $x_{n - 1}$ is large, then $x_n \approx 2x_{n - 1}$. Then $x_{n + k} \approx 2^k x_{n - 1}$, and the expression on the right diverges. Why, then, do you suppose $s(x)$ should approach 0 as $|x|$ approaches $\infty$?

If $s(x_{n-1})$ is small compared to $x_{n-1}$, then $x_n\approx x_{n-1}$.

My bad, not sure what I was thinking...

If $s$ is continuous, $s(L)= 0$ for any $L$ that is a limit of one of your sequences $x_n$.
Suppose there is an increasing sequence $L_m \to \infty$ and $0 < s(x) \le L_{m+1}-x$ for $L_m < x < L_{m+1}$.  Then if $L_m < x_0 < L_{m+1}$, the limit is $L_{m+1}$.
The conclusion is that  no asymptotic bound on $s(x)$ is necessary.
